# Xamarin forms (Visual Studio 2015) open link in facebook app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I´m new in Xamarin.

Is there a way to open a link, for example, "www.facebook.com/google" in facebook app from my app?

if I'm not mistaken, in android is used Katana...

What i found is a way to open it in a native mobile browser.
I used App Links too but not help me.

Thanks

Comment: One thing you could try is to open them by a url like fb://profile/google. Should work for iOS, not sure about the rest.

Comment: I'll try but I think it will not work. I don´t have a profile yet. Thank for a while